# regex - if the first digit is 1 return 1 but if it is 145 return 145 but if its 133 return 133

Tags: regex

here is my regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO4mI1/2)

as the question states:

if the first digit is 1 return 1 but if it is 145 return 145 but if its 133 return 133

sample dataa:

```
K'8134567
K'81345678
K'6134516789
K'61345678
K'643456
K'646345678
K'1234567890
K'12345678901
K'1454567890    <<<--- want 145 returned and not 1 
K'13345678901   <<<--- want 133 returned and not 1 
K'3214567890123
K'32134567890123
K'3654567890123
K'8934567890123
K'6554567890123
```

regex exprtession:

```
K'(?|(?P<name1>81)\d+|(61)\d+|(64)\d+|(1)\d+|(44)\d+|(86)\d+|(678)\d+|(41)\d+|(49)\d+|(33)\d+|(685)\d+|(\d{1,3})\d+)
```

**the regex explained:**

I am interested in the digits after K' 
I am looking to do this using regex but not sure if it can be done.
What I want is:
if the number starts with 81 return 81 
if the number starts with 61 return 61 
...
if the number starts with something i am not interested in return other(or its first digits of 1-3)

The above criteria works:

**but my question is how do I do the following:** 
if the fist digit is 1 then return 1 BUT 
 
if the fist digit is 1 and the 2nd and 3rd digit are 45 return 145 and don't return just 1  
if the fist digit is 1 and the 2nd and 3rd digit are 33 return 133 and don't return just 1

I presume I have to put something inside this part of the regex `|(1)\d+|`

**Som other questions for my own reference:**
Does regex sort the data first?
Is the order of the regex search important to how it is implemented? i deally I do not want this.

Comment: `|(145|133|1)\d+|` add this might do the trick but is the order more importnat in the regex or in the sample data? i do not want duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
K'(?P<name1>81|61|64|44|86|678|41|49|33|685|1(?:33|45)?|\d{2,3})\d+
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO4mI1/8)

Comment: that looks tidier. but this `|1(?:33|45)|1|` could be replaced with `|1(?:33|45)?|` as it is the same as  @m.cekiera done?

Comment: Yes indeed, see my updated regex for a shorter regex.

Comment: made some changes [here](https://regex101.com/r/kO4mI1/9) as wanted to capture 1 ,2  or 3 digits only so had to add a ? if i understand it correctly. but I on;t want to pick up 1 per line but can quite figure that part. hmm but this is not capturing the 0, not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
K'(?|(?P<name1>81)\d+|(61)\d+|(64)\d+|(1(?:45|33)?)\d+|(44)\d+|(86)\d+|(678)\d+|(41)\d+|(49)\d+|(33)\d+|(685)\d+|(\d{1,3})\d+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dE0tB6/1)

Comment: `|(1(?:45|33)?)\d+|` is the first `?` create the option of 43 or 33 (that is 143 or 133). what is the 2nd `?` do?

Comment: @HattrickNZ  the `?:` is for non capturing group (there will be no additional group for the content of paratheses), and second `?` is for optional matching 43 or 33 after 1

Answer (score 0):

regex doesn't sorts anything but the order of your regex is important, actually based on your regex engine it would be a bit different but since most of regex engines use Traditional NFA for parsing string the order is important.

And in this case you can simply us following regex or add it to your regex :

```
(?<=K')1(?:45|33)?
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/rT2yJ0/1